# Check if a data is inside a other table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using a method to compare information in different tables but I am not sure if this method really is the best, I would like some options...

Example:

My system its about scales of work for employees, and I have a table with all the employees and a table of scales, and I wanna check all the employees that is appointed to that scale, I would do like this...

```
foreach($employees as $em) {
    $continue = false;
    foreach( $employees_scales as $es) {
        if ($em->id == $ec->em_id && $ec->date == $date_example) {
            $continue = true;
        }
    }
    if(!$continue){
         // List the employee;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is no valid php code. Take a look at your foreach - there are missing the `$` for some variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you to use Eloquent or DB for getting such information.

- You should create Model (Employee) where will be many to many relationship with second Model (Scale)
- After that you will only have to do like this:

  `$scale->employees; // this will get all employees which has this scale...`

For additional info how to create Many to Many relationship please read this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I understood, the problem is that I have to validate some information, for example time and days, for example I have to know if the employee is appointed to that day and where, and what time, so I had to foreach.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can do like this: `$scale->whereHas('employees', function ($q) { $q->where('what you want here'); })->get();